# Google Maps V.3 custom icons

Tags: image, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, marker

How can I make a similar script for custom marker with Google Maps 3? Just like this with v.2 :

```
var iconBlue = new GIcon(); 
iconBlue.image = 'images/cell1.png';
iconBlue.shadow = '';
iconBlue.iconSize = new GSize(32, 32);
iconBlue.shadowSize = new GSize(22, 20);
iconBlue.iconAnchor = new GPoint(3, 16);
iconBlue.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(15, 15);

var iconRed = new GIcon(); 
iconRed.image = 'images/cell3.png';
iconRed.shadow = '';
iconRed.iconSize = new GSize(32, 32);
iconRed.shadowSize = new GSize(22, 20);
iconRed.iconAnchor = new GPoint(15, 2);
iconRed.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(15, 15);

var iconGreen = new GIcon(); 
iconGreen.image = 'images/cell2.png';
iconGreen.shadow = '';
iconGreen.iconSize = new GSize(32, 32);
iconGreen.shadowSize = new GSize(22, 20);
iconGreen.iconAnchor = new GPoint(-9, 2);
iconGreen.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(20, 15);

var customIcons = [];
customIcons["60"] = iconBlue;
customIcons["240"] = iconRed;
customIcons["350"] = iconGreen;
```

I wrote the following in Version 3 and the marker is not shown.

```
var cellone = new google.maps.MarkerImage("images/cell1.png", 
    new google.maps.Size(20, 34), new google.maps.Point(0,0), 
    new google.maps.Point(3, 16));
var celltwo = new google.maps.MarkerImage("images/cell2.png",
    new google.maps.Size(20, 34), new google.maps.Point(0,0), 
    new google.maps.Point(-9, 2));
var cellthree = new google.maps.MarkerImage("images/cell3.png", 
    new google.maps.Size(20, 34), new google.maps.Point(0,0), 
    new google.maps.Point(15, 2));

var customIcons = [];
customIcons["60"] = cellone;
customIcons["240"] = celltwo;
customIcons["350"] = cellthree;
```

Comment: Your `MarkerImage` definition looks fine, although it is not clear why you put them in an array like this. So the cause of error must be somewhere else. Are there any console errors?

Answer (score 0):

I've recently just did this icon stuff myself. And I initially used the same type of code you used, but that didn't work. Apparently new GIcon() was not functioning properly.

There is a very simple way to change icon though and it doesn't use variables. 
This is what I did.

Declare markerVariable as a global variable.
When you create new markers, one of the lines should say icon : ...

Here is a sample of my code. Of course, you will have to change certain lines to have it working for your program (and you can't use marker with labels unless you change certain functions).

Lastly, icon : ... can be a link or location on your computer.

```
var iconArray = [
                 ["http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png"],
                 ["http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/yellow-dot.png"],
                 ["http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/green-dot.png"],
                 ["http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png"],
                 ["http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/purple-dot.png"],
                 ["http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/pink-dot.png"],
                 ["http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/ltblue-dot.png"]

                 ]; 


function getMarkers() {
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
            marker[i] = new MarkerWithLabel({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                draggable: false,
                map: map,
                icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(iconArray[i]),
                //icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/pink-dot.png"),
                //labelContent: locations[i][3],
                labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(30, 0),
                labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
                 labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75}
            });



        }
}

function initialize() {
  getMarkers();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the way that I want todo is make the Icon categories and then they'll shown belongs to the value. You got it? And I can edit the anchor, size, etc from every image category (if array)
Thanks anyway, I'll learn your script ;)

Comment: Hmm, yeah I had trouble myself manipulating the Icon using GIcon(). Of course, I used markers with labels in mine, so that is what most likely caused the problem. If you decide to modify some of your basic functions/objects, then you also have to edit the marker icon code. I do know that everything you wanted to implement in your code can be done without using GIcon though, as everything you personalize in an icon can be done in the marker and so rather than editing from image, you edit from marker.

Comment: OK then, I'll try to 'operate' your script but if I had a trouble and can't resolve it please help me ok? Thank you very much, catch you later on this page krikara ;)

Comment: Is your map showing and not your markers? This may be a CSS problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Translated version of Mike Williams' v2 "category" example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_categories.html)